# Azure AD - Federated Apps SAML

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, saml, adfs, federated

I need to configure Azure IDP with Gsuite,

My requirement is : when user trying to login to web application by user email id, then it redirects to Gsuite and again asks user email Id to authenticate there too, then it redirects to Azure Ad (IDP) there it will ask user email id and password once successfully authenticated it redirects to user web application, is it possible? like a two factor authentication

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you integrate G Suite application directly from Azur AD enterprise application it won't ask to enter credentials while trying a IDP initiated sign-on. Directly go to myapps.microsoft.com and click the G Suite application it will login. Kindly check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/google-apps-tutorial) for more detailed explanation.

You can enable MFA in the above flow but however the MFA will trigger only after the first factor authentication

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments, but its not MFA, just needs to connect Gsuite as a service provider between user portal and Azure

Answer (score 0):

We have done to turn on SAML single sign on for Gsuite application in Azure, then configure the azure urls in Gsuite SAML third party identity provider.
For references, please find this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1UyevdX09hY

Once configured the setup between Azure and Gsuite, then we have created google API registration for user portal application, then created the IAM for the new application on the registrations.
https://console.developers.google.com/

Then send the request to gsuite from the user portal, it works fine and asks user email id in gsuite (as a service provider) then it redirects to microsoft azure asks user email id and password, then the responses redirects back to user portal successfully

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are a great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)